# How to prove continuity in topological group action of ${\rm{GA}}_a(X)$ on $T(X)$, to make ${\rm{GA}}(X)$ a topological group?

Tags: topological-groups, continuity, affine-geometry

The question comes from the following paragraph of a text on geometry in the context of affine geometry (Marcel Berger et al., "Geometry I", P56-57):

> **2.7.1.3.** If we don't want to resort to the general result 2.3.4, we can proceed in the following way to find a canonical topology for ${\rm{GA}}(X)$: Take $a\in X$, write ${\rm{GA}}(X)$ as the semidirect product $T(X){\rm{GA}}_a(X)$ (2.3.3.8). We have isomorphisms $T(X)\cong\vec X$ and $\mathrm{GA}_a(X)\cong\mathrm{GL}(\vec X)$, so we can successively consider
> canonical topologies on $T(X)$, ${\rm{GA}}_a(X)$, $\underline{T(X){\rm{GA}}_a(X)}$ and ${\rm{GA}}(X)$.

I have assigned canonical topology to $T(X)$ and ${\rm{GA}}_a(X)$ by "copying" it from topological vector space $\vec X$ and $\mathrm{GL}(\vec X)$, respectively. Having topological group $T(X)$ and ${\rm{GA}}_a(X)$ at hand, I then tried to construct the topology onto semidirect product ${\rm{GA}}(X)=T(X){\rm{GA}}_a(X)$ (I underlined it in the excerpt). The construction is standard: we first form the semidirect product $T(X)\rtimes{\rm{GA}}_a(X)$ and then endow it with product topology (cf. e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3955550/how-to-construct-a-topological-group-from-a-semidirect-product-of-two-subgroups)). Since the two subgroups alone do not give enough information to recover the group structure of semidirect product (cf. e.g., [here](http://www.math.columbia.edu/%7Ebayer/S09/ModernAlgebra/semidirect.pdf)), we need to specify a group action. Since the whole group is given (${\rm{GA}}(X)$), the action is known to be necessarily conjugate (cf. e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260844/semi-direct-product-g-cong-n-rtimes-varphi-k)):
$$\phi: {\rm{GA}}_a(X)\to{\rm{Aut}}(T(X)),\quad\phi_f(t)=f\circ t\circ f^{-1},$$ where $f\in{\rm{GA}}_a(X), t\in T(X)$. For $\phi$ to be a topological group action to ensure the resulting topological group on ${\rm{GA}}(X)$, the corresponding function $$\phi(f,t): {\rm{GA}}(X)\times T(X)\ni(f,t)\to f\circ t\circ f^{-1}\in T(X)$$ must be continuous. However, I am not able to prove it; I don't even know how to start. So I asked here in hope that someone with related background can please lend me a hand in establishing the continuity of $\phi(f,t)$. A reference to a textbook or online tutorial is also ok (hope it is not a big theorem in a thick text).

Some of the terminologies follow (you can skip if they are familiar to you): $X$ is an affine space. ${\rm{GA}}(X)$ is the affine group of $X$ under composition of maps. $T(X)$ is the set of translations of $X$ which is a normal subgroup of ${\rm{GA}}(X)$. $X$ is a homogeneous space for ${\rm{GA}}(X)$ so we can define stabilizer ${\rm{GA}}_a(X)$ for a fixed $a\in X$. It can be shown that ${\rm{GA}}(X)$ is a semidirect product of $T(X)$ and ${\rm{GA}}_a(X)$. $\mathrm{GL}(\vec X)$ denotes the linear group of $\vec X$. The canonical topology is induced from the standard topology in $\Bbb R^d$ (cf. e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1956992/canonical-topology)). Here we assume all the vector and affine spaces are finite-dimensional with dimension denoted $d$. Please let me know if you need other information to answer the question. Thank you for your help.